# A weak smart pointer that calls a handler when object being deleted?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I find surprising that people that use `std::weak_ptr` do not find it useful to bind `onDelete` handlers to their references. I've been looking around in `boost` but I haven't found anything like this.

Am I missing something? Is a "bad smell" to rely on something like this? or for some reason it is too niche to be generally useful?

Comment: I don't understand. Wouldn't the destructor of your object get called when the weak pointer is destroyed? Which basically handles onDelete?

Comment: @Nina right but the destructor typically contains code that concerns only with the object domain logic resources, the object should not need to know who is listening to uses or changes of usage on smart references of themselves. Handlers for this are typically for consumers and users of the references

Comment: I could be misreading this question, but I am aware of no such functionality. Are you proposing it be added?

Comment: just aggregate your object into another one `template<typename T> class OnDeleter{ public: T object; ~OnDeleter(){/*your stuff here*/} }`

Comment: @Jeffrey no need to do that, just use a custom deleter, don't think this is what the OP wants though

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `shared_ptr` is basically just a pointer and an atomic reference count, creating and destroying `shared_ptr` instances just involves incrementing and decrementing the reference count so is pretty fast and requires no mutexes.

In order to implement your scheme the `shared_ptr` would need to somehow keep track of all `weak_ptr` instances which would make it much more expensive and probably require a mutex, as this isn't a widely needed requirement it's not worth the cost.

You could use a custom deleter on your `shared_ptr` and when creating your `weak_ptr`s use [get_deleter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get_deleter) to access the deleter and register a callback with it.